# How can I make a line-break work in a LaTeX export without any need for special characters?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, newlines

What I want is to be able to write

> foo
>
> bar

and have my LaTeX export recognise the line-break. Two line breaks rather than one would also be acceptable.

`#+OPTIONS: \n:t` gives the behaviour that I desire, but it makes the gap between unordered lists massive. It is as if each element of the list is treated as if it has a line-break between it.

Appending `\\` to every line would not be acceptable.

Comment: Your question is unclear: In what context do `foo` and `bar` appear? If `foo` and `bar` are on separate line under a headline, they become separate paragraphs in the `.tex` output file and are therefore treated as such by LaTeX.  I would suggest that you provide a complete example input file and describe in detail what you don't like about the output.

Comment: @NickD I intend for them to be plain text in a totally normal section. I can't imagine any context that would change the meaning of this.

Comment: As I mentioned, if you lay them them out as you show (`foo` on one line, an empty line and then `bar` on another line, followed by an empty line), they are separate paragraphs in the `.tex` file and are treated as such by LaTeX. What line-break is not recognized by LaTeX?